# Removing Threaded Socket from Wood Chair Leg

Tags: wooden-furniture

I need to replace the casters on a wood dining chair. I was able to remove the threaded casters. I am not able to remove the threaded caster sockets. There is no lip to pry them out. Is there a tool or some other way to remove them from the chair leg? They have a notch in each side, but they won't turn with a flat tip screw driver. Any advice would be great!

Comment: Turn harder, or show us a photo so we have something to go on. Welcome to DIYSE.

Comment: Do you need to remove the socket? This is likely referred to as a t-nut. Can you just buy new casters that thread into the existing t-nuts?

Comment: you can drill a small hole at an angle that cuts under the lip, allowing you to pry.